# How can I write a trait with @BeanProperty members that must be implemented?

Tags: scala, annotations, traits

I want to define a trait that is used by Java code and it would be therefore convenient to have Java-friendly setters and getters for its members. The `@BeanProperty` annotation does that for me, but I can't get it to work with members that are left undefined in the trait. The following:

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty
trait A {
    @BeanProperty var useFoo: Boolean
}
```

yields the warning `no valid targets for annotation on method useFoo - it is discarded unused. You may specify targets with meta-annotations, e.g. @(scala.beans.BeanProperty @getter) trait A { @BeanProperty var useFoo: Boolean }`

However, it is not discarded unused. A class extending the above trait, for example

```
class B extends A {
    var useFoo = false
}
```

is correctly rejected by the compiler as it does not implement the getter and setter of the BeanProperty. Annotating the `useFoo` field in class `B` with `@BeanProperty` makes it work as expected. However, this seems not to be the proper way to do this, since the above warning is generated. [The documentation for meta annotations](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package%20The%20documentation%20for%20meta%20annotations) suggests that targets are only useful if you want to propagate other annotations onto the generated accessors. So, what is the proper way to define the above trait?

Answer (score 1):

It happens to be a bug in Scala 2.11.x: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8813

My search didn't turn up this issue as in 2.11.1 the warning is "no valid targets for annotation on **method**", while in 2.11.2 it's "no valid targets for annotation on **value**"

Comment: fyi, the method/value discrepancy seems to stem from `val` vs. `var`, not from the version